# form.valid() returns true when form is invalid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form consisting of listboxes and radiobuttons. I submit the form through ajax which sends a post. The actionlink in my controller returns a partial view. If the form is invalid I don't want to clear the selected items in the listboxes, but if the form is valid then everything should be unselected. For some reason form.valid() is always true. The error message shows perfectly so I think there is nothing wrong with the validation. Here are some snippets of my code:

**View: Form**

```
<div id="researchContainer">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResearchCompetence", "Planning", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "researchForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Input.PlanningId)
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <h1>@Html.Label("OverviewResearchCompetences", Labels.OverviewResearchCompetences)</h1>

    <table class="table-output">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.Label("Name", Labels.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.Label("Level", Labels.Level)</td>
                <td class="text-align-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.CurrentResearchCompetences.Count == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("NoCurrentCompetencesRes", Labels.NoCurrentCompetencesRes)</td>
                </tr>
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.CurrentResearchCompetences)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Vtc</td>
                        @{
                            var scoreOutput = new ILVO.Services.EmployeeManagement.ScoreOutput(item.VtcLevel);
                        }
                        <td>
                            @scoreOutput.ToString()
                            @if (!scoreOutput.ToString().Equals("Gevorderd"))
                            {
                                <span class="arrow-up">
                                    @Html.ImageLink("IncreaseLevel", "Planning", new { id = @item.Id, planningId = Model.Input.PlanningId, actionMethod = "JobCompetence" },
                                        "/Content/arrow-icon.png", Labels.IncreaseLevel, "")
                                </span>
                            }
                            @if (!scoreOutput.ToString().Equals("Basis"))
                            {
                                @Html.ImageLink("DecreaseLevel", "Planning", new { id = @item.Id, planningId = Model.Input.PlanningId, actionMethod = "JobCompetence" },
                                    "/Content/arrow-icon.png", Labels.DecreaseLevel, "")
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-align-right deleteLink">
                            @Html.ImageLink("DeleteVtc", "Planning", new { id = @item.Id, planningId = @Model.Input.PlanningId, actionMethod = "JobCompetence" },
                                "/Content/delete-icon.png", Labels.Delete, "")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br />
    <h1>@Html.Label("AddResearchCompetence", Labels.AddResearchCompetence)</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.Label("Disciplines", Labels.Disciplines)</td>
                <td>@Html.Label("Organisms", Labels.Organisms) <a id="clear-organisme" class="button-clear-vtc">Clear</a></td>
                <td>@Html.Label("Techniques", Labels.Techniques) <a id="clear-technique" class="button-clear-vtc">Clear</a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Input.SelectedDiscipline, Model.Disciplines, new { @class = "vtc-listbox-height", @size = 1 })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Input.SelectedOrganism, Model.Organisms, new { @class = "vtc-listbox-height" })

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Input.SelectedTechnique, Model.Techniques, new { @class = "vtc-listbox-height" })

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="after-selection-ok">
        <h1>@Html.Label("ChooseLevel", Labels.ChooseLevel)</h1>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Input.Score, 0, new { @id = "radio1" }) @Html.Label("radio1", Labels.Basic, new { @class = "radio-label" })<br />
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Input.Score, 1, new { @id = "radio2" }) @Html.Label("radio2", Labels.Intermediate, new { @class = "radio-label" })<br />
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Input.Score, 2, new { @id = "radio3" }) @Html.Label("radio3", Labels.Expert, new { @class = "radio-label" })<br />
        <br />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="AddResearchCompetence" value="@Labels.Submit" />
        @Html.ActionLink(Labels.GoBack, "Detail", new { id = @Model.Input.PlanningId }, new { @class = "button margin-left" })
    </div>
}
```

**Controller : Actionlink**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResearchCompetence(ResearchCompetenceInputModel input)
    {
         // do some validations

        // if validations are ok = add competence else return view

        return PartialView("ResearchCompetence", new ResearchCompetenceModel(researchCompetences, currentResearchCompetences, input.PlanningId));
    }
```

**My Ajax Call**

```
$("#researchForm").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("ResearchCompetence")',
            data: $("#researchForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {             
                $("#researchContainer").html(data);
                $("#researchForm").validate();

                if ($("#researchForm").valid()) { // always true
                    $("#Input_SelectedOrganism").val('');
                    $("#Input_SelectedTechnique").val('');
                    $("input[name='Input.Score']").attr('checked', false);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**I also have these scripts loaded:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/site.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl-BE.js")
```

Comment: Can you post your view model, as well? You're using unobtrusive validation, so the validation attributes on the view model will make a difference. Even better: post the rendered HTML emitted from this view.

Comment: @GrahamCharles I "fixed" this by checking if the class of the error message is on the page. It's not a good solution tho.